# Is socket.recv(1024) non-deterministic by design?

Tags: python, sockets

My server uses a single

```
socket.recv(1024)
```

and my client sends a sequence of three messages. The total size of the three messages is smaller than 1024.

It seems the amount of messages received by the client in each reception is different for different runs. Sometimes the server one message; sometimes two or three.

Is socket.recv(1024) non-deterministic by design?

Comment: It is TCP that is non-deterministic by design, in that it only provides a byte-stream, not a message system.

Answer (score 2):

> Is socket.recv(1024) non-deterministic by design?

It depends on what type of socket you are using.

If `socket` is of type `SOCK_DGRAM`, then `recv()` will return the contents of exactly one received (typically UDP) packet.  Note that UDP packets can (and do) get dropped sometimes, so a sent packet might not get received at all, and packets might be received in a different order from the order in which they were sent.  It *is* guaranteed, however, that you will receive either all of a packet, or none of it -- unless your supplied buffer-size is too short to hold all of the packet's data, in which case you'll only get as much data as your buffer can hold, and the remainder of the packet's data will be lost.

OTOH if `socket` is of type `SOCK_STREAM`, then `recv()` will return as many bytes of incoming data as it can currently give you, as determined by the network layer.

For TCP-based `SOCK_STREAM` sockets in particular, it's important to note that TCP guarantees that bytes will be received in the order they were sent, but it does *not* guarantee that they will be received in the same groupings that were originally passed to `send()`.  So for example, if the sending program sends 1000 bytes via a single call to `send()`, the receiving program *might* receive all 1000 bytes via a single call to `recv()`, but it's just as likely that it might receive 500 bytes and then another 500 bytes on the next call, or 25 bytes and then 75 bytes and then 900 bytes, or even (in principle, at least) 1000 separate single-byte deliveries, or any other combination you can imagine.  The TCP layer reserves the right to repackage the byte-boundaries however it sees fit, based on network conditions.  If that is the indeterminacy you are asking about, then yes, it is by design, and your receiving program needs to be smart enough to handle the data appropriately regardless.

Comment: How about Unix socket (AF_unix)? @Jeremy Friesner

Comment: @f.c. it works similarly to a TCP or UDP socket, albeit only within a single host, not across any network.